# Capturing all l letters and excluding words

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying for 2 hours to get my regex working… but only get an headache.

What I wanna get: all "c" in the sequences (not in "Query:" and not in "Sbjct:")

```
    Query: 1   atttatccttttggtcagaattttatatataagtattttttatttttctttggaccaaaa 60
               ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
    Sbjct: 1   atttatccttttggtcagaattttatatataagtattttttatttttctttggaccaaaa 60


    Query: 61  ttttatgcatcacattgtagcttttctgcaccacgccacatcacactacattttttctgt 120
               ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
    Sbjct: 61  ttttatgcatcacattgtagcttttctgcaccacgccacatcacactacattttttctgt 120
```

I get `/\b(?:(?!Sbjct)(?!Query)\w)+(c)/g` but it only capture the last "c" of every line (and I want all "c").

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you clarify what "... I want all 'c'" means?  Do you want them counted?  Do you want a string starting with the first 'c' on the line and ending with the last 'c' on the line with everything in between?  Do you want them removed?

Comment: Yep, sure. I want to capture all "c" to be able to replace them. I will end with something like `query.html(query.text().replace(/(c)/g, '<span class="cystein">c</span>'));`.

Comment: Your example "goal" string looks nothing like your start string - there is no sane transformation from one to the other?

Comment: No, unfortunately. I really need to get `Query: 61  ttttatgcatcacattgtagcttttctgcaccacgccacatcacactacattttttctgt 120` to `Query: 61  ttttatg<span class="cystein">c</span>at<span class="cystein">c</span>a<span class="cystein">c</span>attgtag...120`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Description

If you the global option on the regex replace command then this regex will do the following:

- find each `c` in the string that occur after the first `:`  (semicolon followed by a space)
- assumes there will be only one semicolon and space combination in the string
- captures each `c` so it can be replaced
- allow the string to contain multiple lines
- if the first line starts with `expect:` then ignore all `c` on the entire line
- because this is Javascript it can't use a negative lookbehind

**Regex**

Match: `((?:(?:expect:(?:(?!\r|\n).)*))?(?:(?:\r|\n|\A)+[^:]+:.*?)?)(c)`

Replace with: `$1<span class="cystein">$2</span>`

## Explanation

[image: Regular expression visualization]

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        expect:                  'expect:'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                                 times (matching the most amount
                                 possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
            \r                       '\r' (carriage return)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
           |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
            \n                       '\n' (newline)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          .                        any character
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \r                       '\r' (carriage return)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \n                       '\n' (newline)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \A                       the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )+                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^:]+                    any character except: ':' (1 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      :                        ':'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*?                      any character (0 or more times
                               (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    c                        'c'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Rough Javascript Example**

Note to keep this example easy to read, I used `$1_$2_` as the replacement string instead of the `$1<span class="cystein">$2</span>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var re = /((?:(?:expect:(?:(?!\r|\n).)*))?(?:(?:\r|\n|\A)+[^:]+:.*?)?)(c)



/;
  var sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
  var replacementpattern = "$1_$2_";
  var result = sourcestring.replace(re, replacementpattern);
  alert("result = " + result);
</script>
```

**Resulting String**

Note to keep this example easy to read, I used `$1_$2_` as the replacement string instead of the `$1<span class="cystein">$2</span>`

```
Expect: 61 ttttatgcatcacattgtagcttttctgcaccacgccacatcacactacattttttctgt 120 
Query: 61 ttttatg_c_at_c_a_c_attgtag_c_tttt_c_tg_c_a_c__c_a_c_g_c__c_a_c_at_c_a_c_a_c_ta_c_atttttt_c_tgt 120 
Sbjct: 61 ttttatg_c_at_c_a_c_attgtag_c_tttt_c_tg_c_a_c__c_a_c_g_c__c_a_c_at_c_a_c_a_c_ta_c_atttttt_c_tgt 120
```

**Live Demo**

http://fiddle.re/0qcuea

Comment: Hey! Great answer. Works perfectly. Can I add a specification? If, before the first line containing "Query:", there is a line containing "Expect" (for example). The "c" of "Expect" would be captured. Is it possible to apply your regexp only to lines beginning with "Query:" or "Sbjct"?

Comment: @GregoryLoichot, I've updated my answer to satisfy these new requirements. Have a look and let me know.

Comment: Great, That's  the answer! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean that you want any letter 'c' found in the line heading ignored - ie: if the 'c' is to the left of the colon, it's to be ignored but all c's after the colon are to be captured.  You don't say exactly what is to be done with the captures - so this is what I've come up with;

```
use v5.12;

while (<>) {
    say "Examining line $." ;
    next unless /:/g ;
    while (/ (c+) /gx)  {
        say "  Found \"$1\" at position ", pos ;
    }
}

# when fed the 8 lines above ...
Examining line 1
  Found "cc" at position 19
  Found "c" at position 27
  Found "c" at position 59
  Found "cc" at position 67
Examining line 2
Examining line 3
  Found "cc" at position 19
  Found "c" at position 27
  Found "c" at position 59
  Found "cc" at position 67
Examining line 4
Examining line 5
Examining line 6
  Found "c" at position 19
  Found "c" at position 22
  Found "c" at position 24
  Found "c" at position 32
  Found "c" at position 37
  Found "c" at position 40
  Found "cc" at position 43
  Found "c" at position 45
  Found "cc" at position 48
  Found "c" at position 50
  Found "c" at position 53
  Found "c" at position 55
  Found "c" at position 57
  Found "c" at position 60
  Found "c" at position 68
Examining line 7
Examining line 8
  Found "c" at position 19
  Found "c" at position 22
  Found "c" at position 24
  Found "c" at position 32
  Found "c" at position 37
  Found "c" at position 40
  Found "cc" at position 43
  Found "c" at position 45
  Found "cc" at position 48
  Found "c" at position 50
  Found "c" at position 53
  Found "c" at position 55
  Found "c" at position 57
  Found "c" at position 60
  Found "c" at position 68
```

Note that with data line 3, the 'c' at position 4 is not captured.

This is due to the line `next unless /:/g` which insists on the ':' before any 'c's are taken.  The `/x` turns on "extended mode" regexes which alows whitespace within the regex for better clarity.  When using `/g` - the global match option - the regex can be placed in a while loop and it will repeatedly search for the target starting off from position of the last successful search.

Comment: Sorry, I tagged my question with Perl, but it is Javascript. Could help, but there is no "x" flag on js regex.

Comment: That does change things a little... :-)

Comment: I have been in these shoes once and got 3 downvotes before ever realizing why. Do not change such important tags on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

So just to try and simplify things a bit and not get into crazy look ahead/behind regexes it might be best to just split the line by spaces, grab the nth element that contains the DNA string and then simple

```
dna.replace('c', 'spanny goodness')
```

(Sorry. Answering on phone...)